# How to update Git on Mac OS X from system default to latest

Tags: macos, git

How do I update or upgrade Git (1.7.12.4) to the latest version 1.8.3.4 on OS X (10.8.3)?

I downloaded Git from [git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/) and installed it. But it didn't use the latest version that I installed – instead it used the system default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you downloaded Git from the Git Installer, it'll install the `git` executable in a different place than your system's default one.

The default is `/usr/bin/git`, and the new one is `/usr/local/git/bin/git`. Your shell however will not pick up the latter one if its PATH isn't configured properly. Now, ideally, the path should have been configured by the installer by creating in `/etc/paths.d/git`. This, however, will not take precedence over your default binary.

To always run the newest `git`, you can try adding the following to your `~/.bash_profile` (if you use Bash, that is):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

Then, restart your shell and see if `git` now points to the new version. (Test with `which git`).

Comment: The keyworkd here is 'precedence'. I was doing `PATH=$PATH:$GIT_HOME` and it wasn't working, once I switched to  `PATH=$GIT_HOME:$PATH` where `GIT_HOME=/usr/local/git/bin` it worked!

Comment: And if you install Git via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) (`brew install git`), the Git binary will be located at `/usr/local/bin/git`. Notice the difference with `/usr/local/git/bin/git` which is the location of the Git binary installed via [Git-SCM](https://git-scm.com). As `/usr/local/bin` is already in the `PATH` environment variable on macOS by default, you need not do any additional steps with Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

You can install the latest version of Git using [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew). The installation instructions are at the bottom. You will want to update your `PATH` variable to start with `/usr/local/bin` (or if you install it elsewhere `#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/bin`).

Once you have installed Homebrew, run:

```
brew doctor
```

To install Git:

```
brew install git
```

After setting it up, you will find that there are many other packages that you can easily install using Homebrew.